# Can you get list of all EventSource opened in the browser?

Tags: javascript

For some stuff like frames, you can get list of all frames like  so `window.frames`. Can you do the same with `EventSource` or can I create a global event listener for all events.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Attach an event listener to the window object
window.addEventListener("*", function(event) {
  // The event object contains information about the event that was triggered
  console.log(event.type); // Outputs the type of event that was triggered (e.g. "click", "submit", etc.)
});
```

It is not possible to get a list of all EventSource objects in the same way that you can get a list of all frames using the window.frames property. However, you can use the EventSource.addEventListener() method to attach event listeners to a specific EventSource object and listen for events that are dispatched by that object.

Comment: i think it's still possible but you need to use for loop and get a list of events you want and attach it to eventSource.

Comment: so "*" wont actually fire for EventSource data, correct?